# Suitable long-term sensors for PM, Ozone and NO2

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors

I am totally new to Arduino. I have a Arduino Mega 2560 and I would like to perform long-term observations of PM, Ozone and NO2 (for around a year, outdoors).

Do you have any ideas which sensors might be suitable for this? I have a few sensors in mind (SDS011, Plantower PMS 1003, Sharp GP2Y1010AU0F, Honeywell HPMA115S0...) but since this is my first time doing this kind of stuff, I dont have any experience.

Comment: This sounds like more of an electronics/sensors question than an Arduino question. I'd say first identify the sensor(s) that meet your needs, and then figure out how to interface them with your Arduino.

Comment: Thanks! Since I have no experience at all with this, I wanted to asked experienced users, which sensors may fit my needs. Where can I ask this, if not here?

Comment: The electronics stack exchange would be a good place to start.

Comment: Explain your needs (weatherproof, able to be interfaced with and Arduino microcontroller easily, will last > 1 year without adjustment, etc)